# Получить значение из блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить url картинки (scr) при наведении на блок

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#newSS div div').hover(function(){
var src = $(this).attr('src');
var a = '<a class="fancyimage" href="'+src+'">go</a>';
$(this).prepend('<div class="thumb_bar clearfix">'+a+'</div>');
}, function(){ $(this).children('.thumb_bar').remove(); });

});
```

из блоков

```
   <div id="newSS" class="item-container">
     <a class="item" href="/s/1">
        <div class="thumb_container"
           <div class="img">
              <img id="0" class="thumb" src="913.jpg">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_name">name 1</div>
     </a>
  </div>

  <div id="newSS" class="item-container">
     <a class="item" href="/s/2">
        <div class="thumb_container">
           <div class="img">
              <img id="1" class="thumb" src="7732.jpg">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item_name">name 2</div>
     </a>
  </div>
```

как правильно вытянут url картинки?

если делать так

```
var src = $('#newSS div div img').attr('src');
```

то получаю url первого блока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей выборке:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src');
```

`this` это сам блок `div` на который было произведено наведение курсора. Вам нужно сделать поиск в этом контексте картинки.

Это делается так: `$('img', this).attr('src')`

```
$('#newSS div div').hover(
function(){
    var src = $('img', this).attr('src'); // <<<
    var a = '<a class="fancyimage" href="'+src+'">go</a>';
    $(this).prepend('<div class="thumb_bar clearfix">'+a+'</div>');
}, 
function(){ 
    $(this).children('.thumb_bar').remove(); 
});
```

Уже достаточно много вопросов было связано с поиском элементов по событиям. Можно было и поискать, так же заглянуть в доки `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.item-container').hover(function(){
        var src = $('img', this).attr('src');
        var a = '<a class="fancyimage" href="'+src+'">go (' + src + ')</a>';
        $(this).prepend('<div class="thumb_bar clearfix">'+a+'</div>');
     },
     function(){
        $(this).children('.thumb_bar').remove();
     });
});
```

Приблизительно так. В Вашем примере вы Добавляете ссылку внутри ссылки. Это не правильно. По этому тут я вынес ссылку которая генерируется во внешний контейнер.